# Infinite Loop - ASP.NET execution not timing out

Tags: c#, asp.net, infinite-loop

We have a C# ASHX handler which calls into an unmanaged C library using [DllImport].

In some cases, the unmanaged C library got stuck in an infinite loop, however ASP.NET does not terminate it, causing the WorkerProcess w3wp.exe to consume 100% CPU core infinitely.

In another simple test case, where we add C# infinite loop (while(true){}) inside the C# ASHX handler, IIS terminates the execution as expected.

It looks like IIS does not take into account the execution of unmanaged code through [DllImport] into its executionTimeout logic.

Is this by design? How do we get around this, to get IIS to terminate the execution ?

Comment: IFAIK ASP.Net uses Thread.Abort to terminate requests, and this method works only for managed code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the moment we actually kill the offending thread (not process) directly by checking if that offending thread has consumed too much resources.

Answer (score 1):

The only good way to abort unmanaged code is to run it in a separate process and kill it with Process.Kill().

Answer (score 0):

Since you have unmanaged code, you have to put it in a managed container which [correctly implements `IDisposable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface). Inside the container you can control the life cycle of the task invoking unmanaged method, e.g. kill it after a certain timeout.

Comment: Interesting idea, we'll give it a quick test. Thanks!!

Comment: as the thread is executed in threadpool, there is no easy way to kill it, the unmanaged thread needs to check whether it has been requested to terminate

Comment: @user5133888: If you want to control the life cycle of the thread, you can't run it via `ThreadPool`. Using `Task<T>` or `Thread` instead.